# Как ограничить подключение по vpn только одим соединением в Linux?

Tags: linux, сеть, vpn, linux-mint

Использую для работы Linux mint 18.2. Подключен через проводное соединение. Есть сервер разработки к которому можно подключится только через vpn, айпишник начинается с 10.0. В случае активизации vpn другие сервера в интернете становятся недоступными Возможно ли сделать чтобы соединения которые идут на этот айпи шли через vpn, а все остальные обрабатывались обычным путем без vpn. и как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

в зависимости от реализации VPN (openVPN, strongSWAN, PPTP) это можно отключить по разному, но принцип работы у всех одинаков:

При подключении к серверу VPN клиент устанавливает сетевой маршрут через который "по умолчанию" должен идти весь трафик обычно шлюз у такого маршрута это IP адрес VPN сервера, и потому что на сервере нет маршрутизации для пакетов не предназначенных для него у вас "пропадает" интернет.

Вариант решения проблемы это найти способ в конфигурации VPN клиента отключить создание такого маршрута(использование шлюза VPN сервера в качестве основного маршрута). К примеру в openVPN он отключается удалением\комментированием в client.ovpn строчки

```
redirect-gateway
```

Однако если этой строки у вас нет, значит сервер вам устанавливает (пушит) этот маршрут сам, тогда нужно стартовать вашего клиента с опцией --route-nopull или отключить(удалить\закомментировать строку) установку маршрута на стороне сервера:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```